# Python VKAPI Загрузка товаров в группу

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю перенос товаров с одной группы ВКонтакте в другие. Вроде бы все ничего, но спустя несколько единиц, десятков, сотен товаров появляется ошибка
**"error": "ERR_UPLOAD_ORIGINAL_NOT_FOUND: max size photo file not found"** Фотография загружается нормально, лежит в папке, открывается.
Вроде как помогает увеличение интервала между добавляем товара, но на 300+ товаре все равно появляется аналогичная ошибка.
Сталкивался кто с таким?

```html
link = vkApi.getMarketUploadServer(GROUP_TO)['upload_url']
fp = open('img.jpg', 'rb')
files = {'file': fp}
resp = requests.post(link, files=files).json()
fp.close

r = vkApi.saveMarketPhoto(GROUP_TO, resp['photo'], resp['server'], resp['hash'], resp['crop_data'], resp['crop_hash'])
product_id = vkApi.addProduct(GROUP_TO, title, desc, category_id, price, r[0]['id'])   
r = vkApi.addProductToAlbum(GROUP_TO, product_id['market_item_id'], response['market_album_id'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогла решить данную проблему поддержка в ВК.
Решение следующее.
Отловить, когда от сервера возвращается

```
error: ERR_UPLOAD_ORIGINAL_NOT_FOUND: max size photo file not found
```

и в случае ошибки еще раз вызвать метод

```
getMarketUploadServer()
```

Получить новый id сервера и уже на него загрузить изображение через

```
saveMarketPhoto()
```